# Run a npm based web page on Github

Tags: javascript, node.js, github, npm

I'm trying to run a web page based on npm on my Gituhb repository (paul.github.io) . In it's Readme.md we can find :

````
# Three.js Journey

## Setup
Download [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/download/).
Run this followed commands:

``` bash
# Install dependencies (only the first time)
npm install

# Run the local server at localhost:8080
npm run dev

# Build for production in the dist/ directory
npm run build
```
````

On my  laptop (windowsà I succeed on installing nodejs and npm. However, I didn't find how to install these on github. Any Idea please?

Comment: See https://pages.github.com/, it's only a static server (but you may be able to serve the resulting `dist/`).

Comment: What is a npm based web page? A webpage that's hosted with npm or a (static) webpage that's built with npm?

Comment: You can run build and then host the output files. You can even do it automatically with [github actions](https://gist.github.com/KonradLinkowski/4b2b825d2540c4eecfc5dc1f9e42a87f)

Comment: @jonrsharpe, thank you for your response. Indeed I was able to build and save the content of dist/ in my github and it works !

Comment: @jabaa, it's a static page which requires npm and node.js to work

Comment: @Konard , your response has helped me. As you said, I build it and hosted the dist/ folder in my github. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In the light of the comments, I fixed the issue by building the projet with "npm run build", and I saved the output which has been made in dist/ folder in my Github repository. Thanks again to all contributors.

Comment: Hi, I am running into a similar issue. could you provide more information about what you did to fix the issue? did you run "npm run build" on your computer and then uploaded the output to github? If yes, how did you write the build script? Thanks in advance!